Is it possible to optionally specify a build platform for a service in a Docker Compose file?
I would like to build Docker images defined in a Compose file for different platforms conditionally. For example, for building production images and pushing to container repository, use linux/amd64, but for building development images, use the host's native platform.
For individual Docker image builds, Docker docs recommend using the --platform CLI parameter. However, for Compose, the only way to specify the build platform seems to be the platform service-level parameter.
For setting that parameter dynamically, I suppose the --env-file flag of docker compose CLI could be used, with the compose file specifying platform: ${BUILD_PLATFORM} and the environment file including something like BUILD_PLATFORM="linux/amd64". However, this doesn't allow a "use default host platform" option.
Is there another approach that would allow to only optionally specify the platform, similarly to omitting the --platform when using the non-Compose docker build command?

"For example, for building production images and pushing to container repository" that's describing a CI pipeline, and not something developers should be running with a compose file on their workstation. And in production, you probably want to build multi platform images.

@BMitch I didn't say the compose command is only ran on a developer's machine. The same compose file can be used by both developers and a CI pipeline. The need to be able to define a default host platform is relevant regardless, who runs it and where isn't relevant to the question.

It's possible to run a docker compose build in the CI pipeline, but I think you'll discover you're one of the very few doing that, and may be fighting the tools as a result. Adding multi platform builds, pushing multiple tags for semver, and a lot more are just easier done directly in the pipeline.

@BMitch sorry really not needed to discuss this further.

You should be able to use Compose's default interpolation value to achieve this.
Something like:
    ...
    platform: ${BUILD_PLATFORM:-}
    ...

This worked for me on Debian 12. I was able to build with BUILD_PLATFORM=linux docker-compose build, BUILD_PLATFORM=arm docker-compose build and docker-compose build but not BUILD_PLATFORM=nope docker-compose build. The bogus value results in an error and the following message is printed: "nope": unknown operating system or architecture: invalid argument.
Specifying platform: '' also appears to result in the "default" behavior you're after.

Nice, thank you! Tried this out and it works.
